# Error using spread with Q.all

Tags: javascript, browser, promise, q

I use `Q.all` in conjunction with `spread` in order to migrate two `promise.then` being simultaneously performed on successful resolution of a `promise`:

```
  var p1=112;
var p2=function(data){
    console.log(data);
    return getFormDataWithDropdown(objtype,scenario);
};
var guidRequest=processGuidRequest();
if(!Q.isPromise(guidRequest))
{
    guidRequest=Q(guidRequest);
}   
guidRequest.all([p1,p2])
.spread(function(geoVal,formVal){
    console.log(geoVal);
    console.log(formVal);
}).done();
```

`p1` is a `value` and `p2` is a function that returns a `function` called getFormDataWithDropdown which returns a `promise` or a `value` based on the resolution of a chained set of `promise`s.However I get this error when I run this code:

```
  Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type
```

The error occurs in this function:

```
  Promise.prototype.spread = function (fulfilled, rejected) {
return this.all().then(function (array) {
    return fulfilled.apply(void 0, array);//error occurs here
}, rejected);
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some serious mistakes in your code (and a bit fault in Q, as `.all` apparently accomplishes to return non-arrays).

[`all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall) does *not* take a callback. Its sole argument is either an array, or a promise for an array. It can be called either as a static method:

```
Q.all([…])
```

or as a method on a promise (the promise for an array):

```
Q([…]) .all()
```

Now, this array (wherever it comes from) needs to *contain promises* - the promises that will all be awaited then. You however were passing a number and a function. You should wrap the plain value in a promise with `Q(p1)` (even if not strict necessary), and need to call your function so that it gives you the promise (and if it's really a function for a function as you say, you would need to call it twice).

If you want to wait for the `guidRequest`, you will need a callback function - if you want or not.

Notice also that the `Q.isPromise` on `guidRequest` is unnecessary, just try to cast it with `Q`.

```
var v1=112;
function f2(data){
    console.log(data);
    return getFormDataWithDropdown(objtype,scenario);
};

var guidRequest = Q(processGuidRequest());
guidRequest.then(function(guid) {
    var p1 = Q(v1),
        p2 = f2(guid); // promises here!
    return Q.all([p1, p2]);
}).spread(function(geoVal,formVal){
    console.log(geoVal);
    console.log(formVal);
}).done();
```

Alternatively, you could just have written `return [p1, p2]` and they would automatically have been awaited by the `spread`.